# weird white artifact when trying to color using the sculpt mode

Tags: texturing, sculpting

Here is an image of it:
[image]

I want to just overlay my color into the existing material color, but i get this weird artifact on it, is there a way i can fix this, also I did this because I couldn't find a way to texture paint, how do i texture paint directly on top of an existing material, the tutorials I tried never ended up working, I like the shaders/materials I have already but want to just add a few stylized trick by texture/color attribute pasting. I have included the file in the stack exchanged list but i had to delete few thingss out to make it less then 50 mb, its the fabric material from SouthernShotty's free pack, I just want to know how to not get this weird edge effect and how to paint just on top of the existing material with a new color

[image]

Comment: Your not painting into a texture within sculpt mode your painting the vertices this creates a vertex color group, the look of the paint strokes is determined by the resolution of your mesh. If you want to paint on a texture you'll have to unwrap your model.

Comment: right, even with vertices I am still getting the weird artifact, i subdivided the mesh like 10 times couldn't include on the blend sicne size was too high and i still had the issue of the white artifact, if i were to texture paint on an existing material how would i go about doing that? what is the node setup

Comment: @It'sJustChris in the model thats on the blend file why is there still the weird white artifact even with more vertices then?

Answer (score 0):

I took another look at your file, the white parts are because your vertex color group also contains white, so it's showing up when you use the color group as a color input and as a mix input, try using it as a mix only. If your you are using a color group for mixing I would recommend using white and black.

[image: vertex color help]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, what if i want to use multiple colors, then how can i juse use this setup?

Comment: If you want to just paint more color into it, it'll be better to just create a texture map and mix that with fabric texture otherwise create more vertex color groups and more mix nodes.

Comment: would u be able to get me an example for the texture map? or even the vertex color wit multiple gruops I am a little bit confused thanks a lot for the help